# Should there be a period in "¾-in(.) wrench"?

Tags: abbreviations, periods

> Use a ¾-in wrench to tighten the nut

The above example is from 'Writing in the Technical field' by Thorsten Ewald this above sentence, why didn't we use a period after the inch symbol?

Comment: We don't use periods after abbreviated units of measurement such as in, km, ft, mg, etc.

Comment: Ewald (not Edwald) is Canadian so the book probably reflects Canadian usages; the US has traditionally been more keen on periods.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey we do use periods while using abbreviated forms of imperial units and not metric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more a matter of style than grammar. There is no consistently applied 'rule' which requires abbreviations to be followed by periods ('full stops' in British usage).

The main US English practice is to use periods. Most US style guides recommend not adding a period after abbreviated SI units of measurement:

> Don’t use a period after an abbreviated SI unit of measurement.
>
> 10 cm, 5 ml, 100 kg, 300 ms, 17 km

> Abbreviations of non-metric units, common in American usage, **may** also be followed by a period:
>
> EXAMPLES  mi., yd., ft., in. lb., oz. qt., fl. oz.

Note: 1. 'May', not 'must'. 2. Ewald is Canadian.

[Periods in abbreviations (Editors Manual)](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/periods-in-abbreviations/)

Another guide suggests avoiding periods after all abbreviated measurement units, except for 'in' (inches) in a situation where this would cause confusion with the preposition 'in'.

> Terms of mathematical units: 15 in., 15 ft, 15 kg, 15 m, 15 lb
>
> Generally, you would use these abbreviations only in technical
> writing. There is a space between the number and the abbreviation.
> Notice that we do not put an s after such abbreviations even when the
> plural is indicated. Also, we do not use a period with such
> abbreviations except for in. when it might be confused with the
> preposition in.

[Abbreviations (Grammar.org)](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/abbreviations.htm)

A summary:

> Should You Put a Period After Abbreviations?
>
> **Although it’s technically a style choice**, most US style guides
> recommend putting periods after abbreviations for English units of
> measure such as feet, inches, and pounds. In general, it’s more common
> to use periods in the US than in Britain. With the metric system, or
> more formally the International System of Units, you never use a
> period after the abbreviations.

[Units of measure (Quick and Dirty Tips)](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/units-of-measure/)

Final remarks about style:

> The use of periods (or full stops) in abbreviations can differ between
> British and American usage. This is a matter of style rather than
> grammar, and style guides differ in their recommendations. In this
> article, we discuss general guidelines. Many exceptions exist. As a
> writer or editor, respect the conventions of your field, which take
> precedence over these “rules.” And remember to stay consistent in
> usage throughout a document.

(Editors Manual)